# Android firebase deeplink result null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

This is my code. from `onSuccess` `penddingDynamicLinkData` is null

```
 FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // pendingDynamicLinkData is null

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

In my manifest file

```
<intent-filter android:label="deeplink">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="link.moneylover.me"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Here is my link:

https://link.moneylover.me/addbudget?utm_campaign=test&utm_medium=test&utm_source=test

Previously I've tested and runs great.
Currently I'm using **`firebase version: "11.4.2"`**

Let me know any ideas.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a firebase deeplink (generated from firebase). Use getIntent().getData() to get the link.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the firebase doc

Comment: Yes but this is a regular deeplink, not a firebase deeplink. Therefore, the firesbase deeplink sdk can't extract anything from this url.

Comment: Hi @SimonMarquis, I have this link from the shortened link on the firebase console dynamic link. How to get the correct link?

Comment: Do you have any data associated to this link?

Comment: This link I used to test. And before the test it worked very well.
Also, I have another link. ex: https://anj66.app.goo.gl/RZD6
Can you tell us more about the data associated?

Comment: In my case, for some reason, i start to have this problem in the same activity that has 'android.intent.action.MAIN' action. Moving the action MAIN to another activity allow the handler to receive the 'pendingDynamicLinkData'.

Comment: Getting same error which we extracting the firebase deep link url in Android app. Any one is experienced the same, please help.